# Serve Key: "Key" & Value: "Value" as Key: Value

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, json.net

I have dynamic keys and values that I get from db and then parse with Newtonsoft Json.NET but I don't know how can I serve them as static ones.

## Example

This is what I have

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "IsPublic": false,
    "Notes": "",
    "Values": [
        {
        "Key": "1",
        "Value": "12.02.1991"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what I want

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "IsPublic": false,
    "Notes": "",
    "Values": [
        {
            "1": "12.02.1991"
        }
    ]
}
```

## What I have tried

I tried to do it manually inside my query itself but it didn't work since it's trying to assign the value.

```
return _db.Archives.Single(x => x.Id == id).Batches.SelectMany(x => x.Items).Select(item => new
{
    item.Id,
    item.IsPublic,
    item.Notes,
    Values = item.ArchiveFieldValues.Select(value => new
    {
        /*
        This works just fine
        Key = value.ArchiveField.Key,
        Value = value.Value
        */

        // This is what I tried but it does not work
        value.ArchiveField.Key = value.Value
    })
}).AsQueryable();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, it's complex enough that you probably want to pull it out into it's own function.

You can use an `ExpandoObject` as an object that can have properties dynamically added and removed to it.  Just cast it to an `IDictionary` (it implements that interface explicitly) and add the pairs.  You can type the result as a `dynamic` or `ExpandoObject` based on whichever you prefer.

```
//I know this isn't the real type of your input; 
//modify the parameter to be of the actual type of your collection of pairs
//TODO come up with better name for this function
public static dynamic Foo(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> pairs)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> result = new ExpandoObject();
    foreach (var pair in pairs)
        result.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
    return result;
}
```

Your query can then be modified to have:

```
Values = Foo(item.ArchiveFieldValues),
```

Also note that the query provider most likely won't be able to do anything with that translation, so you'll probably need to throw in an `AsEnumerable` before the select so that this projection is done in linq to objects.

Comment: It works but queries are just horrible. I have `N+1` all the way... But at least it works.

Comment: @Steve Break your select up into two; one that *can* be converted into SQL that just pulls the information that you need, and one that can't be converted into SQL, does it's work in Linq-to-Objects, and maps the information into the actual types that you need using the method in this answer.

Comment: No problem, I just constructed static object from it and only after that I applied the `Foo`. Not it's 2 queries.